# Avoid Windows Phone 8 App closing after resuming from Task Manager

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, taskmanager

My app starts with `Page1.xaml` and with a button goes to `Page2.xaml`. However, if I get on the Task Manager page by holding **Back**, when I resume the app it behaviours differently by the page

- When I'm on Page1.xaml, it reopens the app without problem
- On Page2.xaml the app closes

**Why does it happen?**

Comment: did you attach the debugger? did you get an exception there?

Comment: Where do I have to catch an exception exactly? Or do I simply need to attach the debugger?

Comment: i would advice to attach it and set it to break on all exceptions (go to debug->exceptions ->check the boxes for "thrown")

Comment: I realized I was doing some object assignment into an `ovveride` of the `OnNavigatedTo` method, so I just put them into the main constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`, and now it works. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Please consider answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was doing some object assignment into an `ovveride` of the `OnNavigatedTo` method, so I just put them into the main constructor, after `InitializeComponent()`, and now it works. Sorry for wasting your time!